# Maven/SpringBoot web application: How to apply changes in backend?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, web-applications, compilation

I am working with this package: https://github.com/boylegu/SpringBoot-vue

I am completely new to SpringBoot and Java as a backend for web development. I have a fairly simple question: when I change something in the backend, how can I apply the changes?

Comment: Are you asking about issuing a pull request on Github or about launching a new war file on the server?

Comment: @benji2505 new .jar file

Comment: You package that file with a Maven build command. If you work with an IDE you should find it there. The IDE will guide you through the process.